# Is Chinese food from Chinese restaurants halal?

Tags: food, halal-certification

A cousin of mine brought home some Chinese food that he says a friend of his bought for him. When he brought it home, he asked me if I wanted some, but I really fear that the food might be Haram (it was barbeque chicken with some rice) as it was cooked by non Muslims, and I don't know what they might have put in it. So is this food halal?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for anyone to give a blanket ruling on this, the only way to know if it was prepared according to Islamic principles is to ask the people who prepared it. But if you have doubts, it's safer to avoid it.